# Flash text on web page (html, CSS or other code)

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I am creating a series of web pages for my psychotherapy clients that augments their weekly work in sessions.  The techniques I plan to use are all based on social science empirical data and will be disclosed to users between they start.  The techniques primarily involve this process called priming.  Priming is a form of member that occurs usually out of consciousness (sometimes referred to subliminal priming) or within consciousness (supra-liminal priming). One of these techniques is the flashing (at about 20ms)of words like love, support, hug, caring, etc. that trigger positive associations within people.  The data suggests that this can have a positive effect on other emotional factors but only temporarily.  I am looking to explore whether or not the effect is more lasting if done daily over a longer period of time (1-2 months).  There is considerable data on brain changes that occur over time with mindfulness training.  I am looking into similar changes with secure base (attachment theory) priming.

What I need is a way of flashing a series of words on the web page at about 20ms each so that users can read what's on the page but also receiving the subliminal primes at the same time.  What types of code would you suggest using for this.  As I said, the words would flash at about 20ms, one at a time, at different locations on the page.  There would be a list of about 10-20 different words. And the client will know this is happening, so there is no deception involved.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Daniel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The standard question still applies: what have you tried so far? You need to show SOME work and describe where you are stuck. Asking for a free solution from a zero-start point is frowned upon.

Comment: it might be hard to deliver 20ms accuracy on a web page for a few reasons. you best bet would be rotating out CSS classes, since those rules can be pre-compiled to some degree. you would then have JS add and remove a class for as close to 20ms as the browser could manage.

Comment: You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), or an HTML canvas plus [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) (which should give you a better frame rate).

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DknEr/?

Comment: I'm with dandavis. 20 ms is not a lot; it's very close to the monitor's refresh rate. Are you sure that ordinary computers can handle this with any accuracy? I mean, it's not a software issue.

Comment: Yes, the jsfiddle example is great.  Where in the code would I slow down the appearance (say every 5 seconds) and color of the text (grey)?  Thanks

Comment: I see your point, Diodeus.  Because I am not a programer, but interested in exploring this myself, this may not be the best place to ask questions I am struggling with. I have googled this question with html, javascript, jquery, etc. and haven't really found much.  Then I came across this web site and I thought I'd try putting it out there. I apologize if I inadvertently broke a rule here.  Thanks for taking the time to comment.